# Joining multiple SELECT queries and some simple calculations into one query

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL and fetching a few different values from a table and then perform some basic math on it. Currently three seperate SELECT statements are in use and afterwards I perform some simple addition and subtraction with the outputs I get in Java.

I'm trying to optimize my code but sadly I gotta admit I'm a complete SQL noob. I'm pretty sure there's a way to join these select querys and the calculations so that I actually only get one output but I've not been able to find it.

My table looks something like this:

```
ID | value | inc | timestamp
--------------------------------------
0  | 5     | 4   | 2018-02-01 10:28:21
1  | 8     | 3   | 2018-02-01 10:28:47
...
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
int maxValue = MySQL.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(`value`) AS value FROM `table` where ID = idvalue AND `timestamp` >= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-3,NOW())");

int minValue = MySQL.executeQuery("SELECT MIN(`value`) AS value FROM `table` where ID = idvalue AND `timestamp` >= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-3,NOW())");

int minInc = MySQL.executeQuery("SELECT `inc` FROM `table` where ID = id AND value = minValue");

int output = maxValue - minValue + minInc;
```

Is there a way to shorten it to a single

```
int output = MYSQL.executeQuery( ??? );
```

?

Comment: Could you state what information exactly you're looking for? Now we have to try and figure out from your source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, there's something funky going on with the `maxValue` and `minValue` selects. The `Max()` and `Min()` operators will give you the max and min values of a given column of a given set of rows. Using one of these operators with such a specific `where` (by what seems to be a table's primary key) is probably not what you want to be doing.

Now, answering your question, I think you could do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT MAX('value') as max, MIN('value') as min 
FROM `table` as t
WHERE ...
```

to "join" (careful with this word) the first 2 queries. This is simple `select` syntax: usually, there's no problem with selecting more than a column or an [aggregate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) function at a time. Or, something like:

```
SELECT `inc` 
FROM `table` 
WHERE ID = id AND 
value = (SELECT MIN('value') FROM 'table' WHERE ...)
```

to "join" the last two.

Answer (score 3):

Simply do  `select (select ...) - (select ...) + (select ...)`

In your case, you can do( not tested in real environment )

`` select (SELECT MAX(`value`) AS value FROM `table` where ID = idvalue AND `timestamp` >= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-3,NOW())) - ( SELECT MIN(`value`) AS value FROM `table` where ID = idvalue AND `timestamp` >= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-3,NOW())) + (SELECT `inc` FROM `table` where ID = id AND value = minValue) ``

Answer (score 0):

Single statement is possible using `INNER JOIN` since you are using a single able. Try this

```
SELECT MAX(`a.value`)-(MIN(`a.value`)+b.`inc`) AS Output
FROM `table` a 
INNER JOIN `table` b ON a.ID=b.ID 
AND a.ID = idvalue AND `a.timestamp` >= TIMESTAMPADD(a.DAY,-3,NOW())
AND b.value=(select MIN(value) from table WHERE ID=id);
```